# Display Custom Fields according to Category

Tags: if-statement, woocommerce, conditional-statements, custom-fields

I added Custom Fields to my WooCommerce Single Product Page, with this Code:

```
// DISPLAY CUSTOM FIELDS IN WOOCOMMERCE SINGLE PRODUCT PAGE

add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wpsh_single_posts_custom_meta_fields', 10 );

function wpsh_single_posts_custom_meta_fields(){
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        $post   = get_post( $post_id );
         $month_year = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'month_year' ); // Date field
        $art_size = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'art_size' ); // Text field

 // Date field
                if(!empty($month_year)){
                        echo '<p class="creation-year"><span style="font-weight: bold; color: #4cbb17;">PRODUCT YEAR</span>:  ' . $month_year[0] . '</p>'; 
                }

// Text field
                if(!empty($art_size)){
                        echo '<p class="art-dimension"> <span style="font-weight: bold; color: #4cbb17;">ART SIZE</span>: ' . $art_size[0] . '</p>'; 
                }

        echo '</p>';
        }
```

--- and it gave me this result: https://snipboard.io/dVOLKv.jpg

But two things are missing from my Code and I don't know how to add them:

1.) Show those Custom Fields according to Category.Meaning that, show:
a.) **ART SIZE** and **PRODUCT YEAR** if Category is equal to Artworks.

b.) **CRT PRICE** and **PRODUCT YEAR** if Category is Equal to Bags.

c.) **CRAFT SIZE**, **MATERIAL** and **WEIGHT** if Category is Equal to Crafts.

2.) Hide Custom Fields if value is equal to Null. Meaning that, if these fields are not filled in, with a value, they should not appear.

How do I add these extra rules to my Code above?

Or, can anyone help me with a better Code that could be more flexible than the one I already have?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_the_terms()` to get the category list then filter out based on category id what to display.

Try out this sample code and replace the category id.

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wpsh_single_posts_custom_meta_fields', 10);

function wpsh_single_posts_custom_meta_fields()
{
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $post   = get_post($post_id);
    $month_year = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'month_year', true); // Date field
    $art_size = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'art_size', true); // Text field
    
    $term_obj_list = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );

    if(is_array($term_obj_list)){
        foreach($term_obj_list as $term){
            if($term->term_id == 22){  //here 22 is your category id
                 if ($month_year && !empty($month_year)) {
                     echo '<p class="creation-year"><span style="font-weight: bold; color: #4cbb17;">PRODUCT YEAR</span>:  ' . $month_year . '</p>';
                 }
                if ($art_size && !empty($art_size)) {
                    echo '<p class="art-dimension"> <span style="font-weight: bold; color: #4cbb17;">ART SIZE</span>: ' . $art_size . '</p>';
                }
            }

        }
    }
     
}
```